# Are we able to use MS Access transactions with acCmdSaveRecord?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I know we can use transactions for SQL within Access through the DAO namespace, but are we able to do the same with acCmdSaveRecord, since it's not explicitly linked to the DAO? or Does acCmdSaveRecord have an implicit transaction? If you cannot put acCmdSaveRecord within a transaction, what's the alternative? Explicit SQL?

Forgot to add that I'm a VBA novice, so I am not currently aware which are best practices. Also since I can't comment, I'm taking over existing Access VBA apps, so I don't know the rationale behind using acCmdSaveRecord.

Comment: Why would there be a need for acCmdSaveRecord? Has code changed values in fields for current record on form? Perhaps you should do a test. I use transaction with ADODB connection object. All code examples I see involve SQL actions.

Comment: Why do you use `acCmdSaveRecord` if there is `Me.Dirty = false` ? Forms don't use transactions. But you can add code to start transaction, open `Recordset`, assign it to `Form.Recordset` and manage `Commit` and `RollBack` as you need.

Comment: @4dmonster: Forms _do_ use a transaction - when you delete records manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not as a general rule. So the use of transactions is for VBA code, and sql  or recordset code you have. Unfortunately, the transactions don't apply to forms.

However, you can as a work around:
start a transaction.
Create a recordset.
Shove (assign) the forms record source to the above created record set.

Now, the user can freely edit, change, add, delete to that form, but if you don't commit the record set after all is above and done, then the editing etc. will be ignored. It can be  bit of a pain to set this up, and for sub forms, I never really cooked up a seamless coding approach that worked well.

So if you willing to create a recordset in code and then assign that reocrdset to the forms datasouce, the result is now a form that is bound to the transaction you started in code.